# Columns not lining up properly with Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a design I have mocked up in photoshop using a Bootstrap 12-column guide. Whenever I try to mock this up in Bootstrap, the results are NOTHING like what I want.

[image: My Mockup]

My HTML Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <style>
    body {
    background-color: #cacaca;

    }
    .container{

    }
    /* Remove the navbar's default margin-bottom and rounded borders */
    .navbar {
      margin-bottom: 0;
      border: 0px solid black;
      border-radius: 0;
b     ackground-color: #2a2b2d;
    }

    .bottom-nav {
      background-color: #1d1e20;
      border: 0px solid black;
      margin-top: 0;
    }
    /* Set height of the grid so .sidenav can be 100% (adjust as needed) */
    .row.content {
      height: 100px
    }

    /* Set gray background color and 100% height */
    .sidenav {
      padding-top: 20px;
      background-color: #f1f1f1;
      height: 100%;
    }

    /* Set black background color, white text and some padding */
    footer {
      background-color: #555;
      color: white;
      padding: 15px;
    }
    .text-left{
      margin-top: 105px;
        border:1px solid black;
        background-color:white;
      }
    .blog{
        border:1px solid black;
        background-color:white;
        margin-right: 10px;
}
  .sidebar{
    margin-left: 10px;
        border:1px solid black;
        background-color:white;
}

    /* On small screens, set height to 'auto' for sidenav and grid */
    @media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
      .sidenav {
        height: 280;
        width:280;
        margin:20px;

      }
      .row.content {height:auto;}
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>

<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Logo</a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">

      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
         <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Projects</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
 <nav class="bottom-nav">
 &nbsp;
</nav>
<div class="container text-center">
  <div class="row content">
    <div class="col-md-3 text-left">.col-md-3</div>
    <div class="col-md-3 text-left">.col-md-3</div>
    <div class="col-md-3 text-left">.col-md-3</div>
    <div class="col-md-3"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-9 blog">.col-md-9</div>
    <div class="col-md-3 sidebar">.col-md-3</div>
  </div>
</div>

<footer class="container-fluid text-center">
  <p>Footer Text</p>
</footer>

</body>
</html>
```

My problem is that in my mockup, I have 10px of "gutter" between each column, whenever I add this in with "margin" CSS, it throws the page out of whack.

Also, the main blog block (the big white one) is 9 columns. the sidebar(black thing next to it) is 3 columns. Whenever I input the respective columns WITH margin, it pushes it to a new line. Like so:

[image: What ACTUALLY happens]

I'm really new to bootstrap, but it's throwing me for a loop! Any help is appreciated! I would really like to learn this properly.

Also, is there any way to center the columns like I have in my mockup?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first: remove the margin-right and margin-left from .blog and .sidebar.
then: you can put a div inside div.col-md-3 with width:100% and background-color: white, and remove background-color:white from div.sidebar.

```
.blog{
    border:1px solid black;
    background-color:white;
}
.sidebar{
    border:1px solid black;
}
.with-space {
    width: 100%;
    background-color:white;
}
/*-------------------*/
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-9 blog">col-md-9</div>
<div class="col-md-3 sidebar">
  <div class="with-space">col-md-3</div>
</div>
```

[image]

I hope it helps you...

Comment: Bootstrap's grid has a default gutter of 30px (15px left, and 15px right for every .col-*)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried closing the container div after the first row, and opening a second container for the second row? Bootstrap does a wrap-around type thing when you exceed 12 columns in a container